# github protected branches don't offer any real security

Tags: git, security, github

In [github's docs](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/) they mention protected branches as a way to "keep your project and pull requests organized and safe". However, after doing some research there is no real added security to the model. Is the following description inaccurate?

A protected branch in github relies on tagging commits using the status api as 'successful'. Then, github will prevent merges, force-pushes etc. to a desired branch (ie. master), unless the pull-request to be merged has been tagged via the API as successful.

The problem is that anyone with push access to the repository can manually apply a successful status to their commit via the API.

For example:

- a user has a pull request into master who's build has failing tests
- github will not allow the pull-request to be merged as the status is failing
- the developer can manually use the API to tag their commit as successful, bypassing the test checks
- failing code gets into the protected branch

Protected Branches can offer some nice code quality checks, but since there are no restrictions on the Status API then there is nothing to prevent those checks being bypassed.

Comment: Can you clarify - are you just asking if your current description is accurate?

Comment: If you have a collaborator evil enough to purposefully bypass protected branches and your repo's official workflow by manually fiddling with the API, you probably shouldn't trust that person enough to have any kind of commit access to your repository. Next thing you know, that person will be inserting backdoors in your code :)

Comment: How would you know if you could trust someone until after the damage is done? We are implementing these controls as a response to 3rd party audits for certain security certifications.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed after talking with Github that if you have push access then you also have the ability to use the status api; there is no finer grain of control available.